# uniqueness of neutral element for matrix addition confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Basic Linear Algebra 2e (T.S.Blyth and E.F.Robertson) and have come across the following theorem:

---

**Theorem**

There is a unique $m \times n$ matrix $M$ such that, for every $m \times n$ matrix $A$ one has $A + M = A$.

**Proof**

Consider the matrix $M = [m_{ij}]_{m  \times n}$ all of whose entries are $0$; i.e. $m_{ij} = 0$ for all $i,j$.

For every matrix $A = [a_{ij}]_{m \times n}$ we have:

$A + M = [a_{ij} + m_{ij}]_{m  \times n} = [a_{ij} + 0]_{m  \times n} =[a_{ij}] = A$

To establish the uniqueness of this matrix M, suppose that $B = [b_{ij}]_{m \times n}$ is also such that $A + B = A$ for every $m \times n$ matrix $A$.  Then in particular we have $M + B = M$.

---

**Question**: I understand everything up to but not including the last sentence.  How do we get to $M + B = M$?  Please dumb down the answer as much as possible - my math is very rusty!

Comment: $M+B=M$ is just an instance of the more general "$A+B=A$ for all $A$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a technique very common in uniqueness proofs. It goes like this:

1. Assume $X$ and $Y$ both have the properties that we want
2. Show that actually, $X = Y$, so $X$ was unique.

In this case, they are using the fact that that $A + B = A$ for any matrix $A$ to say that $M + B = M$. This is allowed because $M$ falls under the umbrella of "any matrix."

Does that make sense? feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  So they are saying that A and M are equivalent?

Comment: No. The point is that $A + B = A$ for *any* matrix $A$. So we take a matrix and put it where $A$ is, and the statement is true. So, since $M$ is a matrix, we can stick it where $A$ was, and the statement is true.

Comment: All is clear now.  Thank you!